Detailed exp does Euler's method fail for second order sinusoidal ODE?
I am trying to explain, for a seminar, why this ODE fails with Euler's method.
$$ \partial^2_x y= \sin(x) $$ for boundaries, $L=2\pi$, $y(0)=y(L) = 0,\ y'(0) = y'(L) =-1$, which has exact solution $$ y = -\sin(x) + \frac{\sin(L)}{L}x.$$
You use Euler's method to split this into two first order ODEs, $v = y'$:
$$ \begin{pmatrix} y' \\ v'\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} v \\ \sin(x)\end{pmatrix}$$.
Implementing this, Euler's method diverges and is due to the oscillatory nature of the problem. I know that this is simple to solve analytically or by using RK, FD or FEM etc.
I was hoping that someone has a more rigorous reason behind this but I cannot get my head around as to why!
TIA!

how do you find $v(0)$?

Good point, I should have included the exact solution! We know that y'(0)=y'(L) =-1  for the periodic case.

Then I could not see why Euler method cannot work, is your time step sufficiently small?

can you make your time step very small and run the code? You won't get $y(L)=0$ of course, but that error will be smaller as $dt$ gets smaller.

It would be nice if you could add (using the [edit] link) a table to the above presented tests, that is $dt$ to $y(L), y'(L)$. This would allow to see if the behavior is as expected or if you have to search for implementation errors.

You can try some symbolic iterations.
The state vector $$Y=\begin{pmatrix}y\\
v
\end{pmatrix}$$
has derivative $$f(x,Y) = \begin{pmatrix}v\\
\sin x
\end{pmatrix}$$
and I.C. $$Y_0 = \begin{pmatrix}0\\
-1
\end{pmatrix}$$
You can work out some Euler method iterations until you figure out the solution pattern
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
n & x & Y_{n}\\
\hline 0 & 0 & \begin{pmatrix}0\\
-1
\end{pmatrix}\\
1 & h & \begin{pmatrix}0\\
-1
\end{pmatrix}+h\begin{pmatrix}-1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-h\\
-1
\end{pmatrix}\\
2 & 2h & \begin{pmatrix}-h\\
-1
\end{pmatrix}+h\begin{pmatrix}-1\\
\sin h
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-2h\\
h\sin h-1
\end{pmatrix}\\
3 & 3h & \begin{pmatrix}h\left(h\sin h-3\right)\\
h\sin2h+h\sin h-1
\end{pmatrix}\\
4 & 4h & \begin{pmatrix}h\left(h\sin2h+2h\sin h-4\right)\\
h\sin3h+h\sin2h+h\sin h-1
\end{pmatrix}\\
5 & 5h & \begin{pmatrix}h\left(h\sin3h+2h\sin2h+3h\sin h-5\right)\\
h\sin4h+h\sin3h+h\sin2h+h\sin h-1
\end{pmatrix}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
n & n\,h & \begin{pmatrix}h\left(h\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}\left(\left(n-1-i\right)\sin i\,h\right)-n\right)\\
h\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\sin i\,h\right)-1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{array}$$
At this point, the solution for $v$ depends on the following sum
$$v_n =\mbox{-}1 + h \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\sin i\,h\right) = \mbox{-}1 + \tfrac{h}{2}\cot\left(\tfrac{h}{2}\right)-h \tfrac{\cos\left(h\left(n-\tfrac{1}{2}\right)\right)}{2\sin\left(\tfrac{h}{2}\right)}$$
The above converges to $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} v_n = 1$ so if Euler fails it must be due to the $y$ solution which does not have an analytical expression.
... So inconclusive at this point.

But $\frac{h}{2\sin(h/2)}$ has limit 1 for $h\to0$.

@LutzLehmann - you are correct. I have updated my response accordingly.
